# I want to send the gif on to server in Multipart in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making the `Gif` from video where I am getting multiple images and converting the array(which contain the `images`) in to `NSData` and sending it on to server in multipart. So I'm sending the data on to server now my `gif` post succesfully on to server but it is not accessible when I'm assinging the `url` to my `image`. Can you please help me for this.

I am using below code:

```
    //set the Gif image on uiimageview
    imageSelectedGif.animationImages =_ArrGifImagesSelected;
    imageSelectedGif.animationDuration = 5.0f;
    imageSelectedGif.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [imageSelectedGif startAnimating];
Gifdata = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_ArrGifImagesSelected];
    //set the Gif image on uiimageview
    imageSelectedGif.animationImages =_ArrGifImagesSelected;
    imageSelectedGif.animationDuration = 5.0f;
    imageSelectedGif.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [imageSelectedGif startAnimating];
Gifdata = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_ArrGifImagesSelected];
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager2 = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters=@{
                               @"type":@"gif",
                               @"user_id":[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"LoginWebData"]valueForKey:@"userID"],
                               };
    NSLog(@"%@",parameters);
    manager2.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager2.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager2.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:300];
    manager2.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;

    //giving the correct format to json
    manager2.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager2.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
    //set the header do http request
    [manager2.requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]dictionaryForKey:@"LoginWebData"]valueForKey:@"token"]]forHTTPHeaderField:@"token"];

    [manager2 POST:[kBaseUrl stringByAppendingString:@"save_post"] parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

        //this is for creating multipart image with extension
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:Gifdata name:@"image" fileName:@"photo1.gif" mimeType:@"gif"];

    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"operation=%@",operation);
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"operation=%@",operation);
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];****
```

Comment: can you at least leave four spaces to your code for better readability !!

Comment: where are you accessing your uploaded image ?

Comment: @BajrangSinha Did you get your solution? ;) I can answer if you want!